# How to integrate SwiftLint with an iOS app using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift-package-manager, swiftlint

I'm creating a new iOS app using Xcode 11 (beta 5), and I'd like to use Swift Package Manager instead of CocoaPods for managing dependencies.

A common pattern when using SwiftLint and CocoaPods is to add SwiftLint as a dependency and then add a build phase to execute `${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint`; this way all developers end up using the same version of SwiftLint.

If I try to add SwiftLint as a SwiftPM dependency in Xcode, the executable target that I need is disabled:

[image: Add Package Screenshot]

I was able to fake it by creating a dummy `Package.swift` with no product or target, and running `swift run swiftlint` in my build phase, but it feels like a hack:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "dummy-package",
    products: [],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint.git", from: "0.34.0")
    ],
    targets: []
)
```

Is there a way do this without creating a dummy package? Or is Swift Package Manager just not the right tool for this particular use case?

Comment: FWIW: there's a [new/future/accepted feature](https://forums.swift.org/t/package-manager-extensible-build-tools/10900) that is WIP at the moment, that will allow us to do what you want essentially, and even more. Let's hope it's gonna come soon to us!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*All* methods of abusing iOS code dependency managers to run build tools are hacky and weird.

The correct way to version SPM-compliant tool dependencies is to use [Mint: A package manager that installs and runs Swift CLI packages](https://github.com/yonaskolb/Mint). See also [Better iOS projects: How to manage your tooling with mint](https://number42.de/blog/2018/07/03/mint-2018-07-03-mint.html).

Answer (score 17):

I am using Xcode 14.3. You can integrate SwiftLint as a Swift Package into your project.

1. In your project, import SwiftLint within the `Package Dependencies` section.

   The SwiftLint GitHub url to add: `https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint.git`
2. Once the package is loaded, you will be asked to add `SwiftLintFramework` and/or `swiftlint`.

   Do not tick the boxes. Just click on the `Add Package` button.
3. Go to your Xcode project target and into the `Build Phases` tab:

   Click on the `+` button under `Run Build Tool Pug-ins`.
   From there, add `SwiftLintPlugin`.
4. Build your project, and Xcode will ask to `Trust & Enable All` plugins.

   Click on this button to enable SwiftLint plugins.

SwiftLint is now working on your Xcode project, and you should see the warnings and errors triggered.

You can add custom rules by adding a `.swiftlint.yml` file into the root of your project. You can then edit this file with your desired rules. For more insights on the rules you can add, look up the [SwiftLint rules](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/rule-directory.html).
For an example of how the custom rules are set, you can look up the `Configuration` section of the SwiftLint package index [documentation](https://swiftpackageindex.com/realm/SwiftLint).

Answer (score 3):

Not perfect solution, but it works. I've found it [here](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/3840#issuecomment-1085699163)

1. Modify target section of `Package.swift`

```swift
targets: [
    // 1. Specify where to download the compiled swiftlint tool from.
    .binaryTarget(
        name: "SwiftLintBinary",
        url: "https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/download/0.47.1/SwiftLintBinary-macos.artifactbundle.zip",
        checksum: "cdc36c26225fba80efc3ac2e67c2e3c3f54937145869ea5dbcaa234e57fc3724"
    ),
    // 2. Define the SPM plugin.
    .plugin(
      name: "SwiftLintPlugin",
      capability: .buildTool(),
      dependencies: ["SwiftLintBinary"]
    ),
    // 3. Use the plugin in your project.
    .target(
        name: "##NameOfYourMainTarget",
        dependencies: ["SwiftLintPlugin"] // dependency on plugin
    )
  ]
```

2. Create `Plugins/SwiftLintPlugin/SwiftLintPlugin.swift`

```swift
import PackagePlugin

@main
struct SwiftLintPlugin: BuildToolPlugin {
  func createBuildCommands(context: PluginContext, target: Target) async throws -> [Command] {
    return [

        .buildCommand(
            displayName: "Running SwiftLint for \(target.name)",
            executable: try context.tool(named: "swiftlint").path,
            arguments: [
                "lint",
                "--in-process-sourcekit",
                "--path",
                target.directory.string,
                "--config",
                "\(context.package.directory.string)/.swiftlint.yml" // IMPORTANT! Path to your swiftlint config
            ],
            environment: [:]
        )
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error : `No such module 'PackagePlugin'`

Answer (score 2):

I use [xcodegen](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen) to genreate a Xcode project that has the ability to run scripts. This lets me see swiftlint warnings in Xcode while developing packages.

This tool creates a Xcode project from a [project.yml](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/blob/master/Docs/ProjectSpec.md) definition. In that definition, you can add a script that runs swiftlint as a post compile task. [Example](https://gist.github.com/janodev/cc4fc2cdfbeb2d1b18c964e7e95ff0db).

Advantages of this method:

- swiftlint warnings in Xcode.
- Xcode settings beyond what SPM offers.

Disadvantages:

- You rely on a third-party tool that could break or go away. However, you can drop this dependency at any time and go back to edit the Package.swift in Xcode.
- You need to learn to write project.yml files.
- If you use SPM bundles you need to generate the bundle accessor yourself.

---

A word about generating a bundle accessor. This is needed when working from a Xcode project because only SPM generates the file `resource_bundle_accessor.swift` to the project. If you already compiled after opening the `Package.swift` with Xcode, the file should be here:

```
find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData* -iname resource_bundle_accessor.swift
```

You can add it to the project, but if you are creating a framework, the bundle accessor can be as simple as:

```swift
import class Foundation.Bundle

// This file is only used when using a xcodegen-generated project.
// Otherwise this file should not be in the path.

private class BundleFinder {}

extension Foundation.Bundle {
    static var module = Bundle(for: BundleFinder.self)
}
```